# Change password first Log In sudo su with Cloud-init

Tags: linux, sudo, password, cloud-init

I'm trying to implement this rule with cloud init but I can't, I would like the user to have a password entered by me but as soon as he executes the sudo su command, the system forces the user to change password. How can I do this via Cloud-Init? I state that the user connects in SSH and is not prompted for a password.

```
- name: prova
groups: sudo
plain_text_passwd: 1234
sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) ALL']
lock_passwd: false
chpasswd: {expire: True}
ssh_pwauth: false
```

I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-passwords):

> The expire key is used to set whether to expire all user passwords specified by this module, such that a password will need to be reset on the user’s next login.

If you don't want to expire the user, the expire key shouldn't be set to true.